# I want to reward someone for writing a good answer for my question, but without starting a bounty

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation, bounties

I want to reward to someone for writing a good answer for my question.

**This reward system will be only for the question owner and who gave the answer.**

**Users only will give a reward for an answer of his/her asking a question ... Not other peoples' questions.**

As far as I know: I need to wait a day to start a bounty. But I don't want to waste my time.

Think also about: They gave me more time to resolve my issue. Sometimes people discuss for multiple problems. People are eager to help each other.

Comment: So you can upvote the answer and they will get some rep, I really don't get what you are asking for here and I don't see how awarding a bounty tomorrow wastes your time, you don't have to sit at your computer,. staring at the screen for 24 hours until bounty is available, just get on with your your day. Rep is the reward here, what exactlly are you suggesting as an alternative?

Comment: [Cross-posted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/402095/2452869) on StackOverflow Meta

Comment: What you want doesn’t exist.  However, this is indeed, a duplicate of the existing question

Comment: @noor _"**Users only can reward for answer of his asking question .. Not Others people question**"_ That's not true. Users can place bounties outside of their own questions.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ  this is i want for without starting a  bounty

Comment: Why? What's wrong with a bounty?

Comment: @Mast  i mention it on the question

Comment: It is absolutely unclear.

Answer (score 8):

The (arguably) best way to thank them is probably answering one of their own questions.

I assume you've already upvoted the answer; *don't* go to their profile and vote on the others, that's serial voting and will be reversed.

Having to wait another day for a bounty isn't that much of a problem, IMHO, compared to the 11 years of existence of Stack Overflow. An *advantage* is that the answer is still 'fresh' and has the attention of the community; a bounty bumps it to the top of the page again, which has more effect when the answer is older.